# CocoaPods and Swift - Safe to rely on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

**Re-worded Question**
Does relying on CocoaPods create risks for long term application health when iOS is updated? What steps can be taken to limit the risk?

**Original Question**
I am just getting started using cocoapods with swift to import impressive libraries such as EVCloudKitDao and YapDatabase. These pods make my life much easier *NOW*.

**I'm wondering if relying on pods is a bad idea from a design standpoint.** I am not sure how at risk I am for something to stop working in the future and completely screw up my app... I've never had to update pods to keep something working, and I'm unsure of how dangerous this is for future tenability. Some of these (most) are written in objective-c, and I'm programming in Swift if that makes a difference.

Is using CocoaPods a safe idea in a project? Until now I've been staying away from them, but some of them are so awesome...

Comment: Flagged for 'primarily opinion based'

Comment: To me it's not a bad idea to use them at all. A lot of people are using them so consider it safe and stable as well. You use libraries in your day to day work as well, don't you?
Cocoapods gives you ease in using different libraries, staying up to date with them(if you want, or you can just stick to a version of the library for which your code works.)

Comment: Am I supposed to post opinion based posts elsewhere? New to SO - want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

Comment: Really glad you're not taking it the wrong way. I think maybe it belongs to programmers.SE. 
If you have more objective question regarding cocoapods, like how to install, update, restrict update, SO is definitely the place.

Comment: Ok - I'll try and make sure to place it in the correct area next time (apologies). I just had a big run in with using the appDelegate as a singleton so I am hoping to get my theory down right before I start new projects now :(

Comment: Just a heads up: This question (and all primarily subjective questions) would get closed on programmers.se  Please take a look at P.SE's posting guidelines before posting there or recommending others post there.  Thanks.

Comment: So... where would this type of question really belong? I'll read through the descriptions now but I'm just wondering!

Comment: Nowhere at Stack Exchange I'm afraid.
["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: Absolutely a risk to introduce an external dependency like Cocoapods to a project, anyone who says other ways likely has not had to scale or long term experience in complex migrations/upgrades or enterprise scaling.

Comment: I highly recommend against using CocoaPods. It is extremely buggy and is constantly changing. Your initial installs will be easy, but after that modifying and upgrading will be a complete nightmare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are useful until you get a pod that conflicts with another pod...

If you add all the pods you need and they work then great! I've only had an issue with them a handful of times in the past

If you edit the podfile so that it only uses a specific version of each pod that you know is working then it'll never break even if they update their framework

Do this by doing something like:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.0'
```

This will only use v2.0 of AFNetworking for example.

If at some point you do find that they are screwing up your project then it's not a big deal to remove pods and manually add all your frameworks

Comment: So, essentially, if the pod works from day 1, and you don't update it - it shouldn't "break" from future ios updates? That is my primary concern

Comment: Correct! As long has you have that version restriction on it then it'll never "auto update" when you run an update on your cocoapods

Comment: Also if you feel the need to try out newer updates you can do it, if it breaks, change the version number back, update again and it'll be back to it's working state

Comment: Super helpful in clarifying the risk for me. Thank you!

Comment: @RyanOfCourse As I know **pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'** will use version from 2.0 to 2.9, in case you need 2.0 only use **pod 'AFNetworking', '2.0'**

Comment: @AlexZd Edited - Thanks.. it's been a little while since I had to do it

Answer (score -1):

I have been using CocoaPods with Swift project. The Objective-C libraries compiled and worked fine. I guess it depends on what libraries you are planning to use. But the ones that you mentioned should work fine.